# Is android notepad sample not reachable from documentation?

Tags: android

Anyone knows why the familiar Notepad sample - and perhaps others - is not reachable from

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

I found this page only by googling
http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html

(I wanted to ask this in the developer android newsgroup at google groups but beginner level questions are [directed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers) here to SO).

Comment: The only person who can definitively answer this works for Google and is unlikely to be monitoring Stack Overflow. Anyone else's answer will be opinions or guesswork.

Comment: No answers there. Perhaps because it specified Eclipse rather than their flagship Studio IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future visitors, [here's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+archive/master/samples/NotePad.tar.gz) the new link to the sample.

Edit:
In case the link becomes invalid, you can search on [googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/)  also known as Google git, in the samples folder.